# how to extract different lines word text and output in two text files using python3.6.4

Tags: python, csv, text, output

I am try to extract words from different lines(after nine spaces-see example) and want to output in two text files using python3.6.4 Example of my text file name contains.

```
personal:01
personal:apple
colorsid:fruitgreen
personal:01
personal:banana
colorsid:fruityellow
personal:01
personal:stawberry
colorsid:fruitred
personal:01
personal:mango
colorsid:fruitdarkgreen
```

I want to extract in two text files like below(output):-
So, textfile1.txt contains:

```
apple
banana
stawberry
mango
```

and so, textfile2.txt contains:

```
fruitgreen
fruityellow
fruitred
fruitdarkgreen
```

(So here personal:01 is ignored)
I tried to search a solution everywhere but not got,how can we prepare a script in python3.6.4 where it can separate like this.I am testing it with a huge textfile list.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at the pandas module, with [read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) 
If it's laid out exactly as it is in your example, you can set the separator to ":" and then filter the dataframe based on the value of the first column (and also filter out any `01` values in the second column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line, and add it to the correct file based on the the contents after `:`:

```
with open('data.txt') as in_file:
    with open('file1.txt', 'w') as out1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as out2:
        for line in in_file:
            _, value = line.strip().split(':')
            if value != '01':
                if value.startswith('fruit'):
                    out2.write(value + '\n')
                else:
                    out1.write(value + '\n')

    print(open('file1.txt').read())
    print(open('file2.txt').read())
```

Which outputs:

```
apple
banana
stawberry
mango

fruitgreen
fruityellow
fruitred
fruitdarkgreen
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way using the `pandas` library. Just replace `pd.read_csv(mystr)` with `pd.read_csv('input_file.csv')`.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO('''personal:01
personal:apple
colorsid:fruitgreen
personal:01
personal:banana
colorsid:fruityellow
personal:01
personal:stawberry
colorsid:fruitred
personal:01
personal:mango
colorsid:fruitdarkgreen''')

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, names=['Col1', 'Col2'], delimiter=':')

#         Col1            Col2
# 0   personal              01
# 1   personal           apple
# 2   colorsid      fruitgreen
...
# 9   personal              01
# 10  personal           mango
# 11  colorsid  fruitdarkgreen

x = df.iloc[df.index[1::3], 1]  # ['apple', 'banana', 'stawberry', 'mango']
y = df.iloc[df.index[2::3], 1]  # ['fruitgreen', 'fruityellow', 'fruitred', 'fruitdarkgreen']

x.to_csv('file1.csv', header=False, index=False)
y.to_csv('file2.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: how to apply for a huge file?

Comment: @RajBanra, sorry i don't understand your question. This should work for any data set that fits in memory. If the file size is 2GB and you have 8GB free memory, for example, you should be fine.